# Go言語でパスワード付きzipファイルを作成する方法について

Tags: go

## 実現したいこと

Goバッチ処理内でのパスワード付きzipファイルの作成

## 調査したこと

・標準パッケージarchive/zipにはパスワード付きzipを作る機能は備わっていない
・実現するには別途パッケージを追加する必要がある
・github.com/yeka/zip、github.com/alexmullins/zipを発見

## 課題（質問）

Go言語初学者のため基本的なimport手順が理解できていません。
そのためgithub.com/yeka/zip、github.com/alexmullins/zipをインポートしたところ

```golang
import (
    "archive/zip"
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/hex"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    yzip "github.com/yeka/zip"
)
```

下記のようなメッセージが出て利用できませんでした。

```
could not import github.com/yeka/zip (no required module provides package "github.com/yeka/zip")
```

以下のいずれかがわかれば解決できると思いますのでご回答よろしくお願いいたします。
・標準パッケージで実現可能ならその方法
・github.com/yeka/zip、github.com/alexmullins/zipいずれかで実現可能ならその方法
・それ以外の実現可能な方法

Comment: [zip package - github.com/alexmullins/zip - pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/alexmullins/zip#section-readme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no required module provides package "github.com/yeka/zip"

このエラーについては、Go modules を利用しているのに `go.mod` に `github.com/yeka/zip` の情報が書かれておらず、`github.com/yeka/zip` を見つけることができていない、というエラーになっているように見えます。

たとえば `go mod tidy` を行うことで `go.mod` に `github.com/yeka/zip` が書き込まれないでしょうか。

また、そもそも `go get` ができているかも合わせて確認してみてください。

Comment: ご指摘の通り go mod が実行されていませんでした。
ご回答ありがとうございました。